# What is the best way to improve the performance of my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Currently I have the following two tables (shown here somewhat simplified):

users: (userId, username, email, name)
permissions: (id, userId, permission)

The permission field may contain, for example, something like canRead, canWrite, canDelete, etc. Each user can have any number of permissions.

I have now written a query to display all users and to get the permissions of each user as an extra boolean column. For example, this is what a result of the SQL script should look like for two users registered in the system:

```
userId: 1, username: "testuser", email: "test@test.com", name: "testname", canRead: 1, canWrite: 0, canDelete: 0
userId: 2, username: "anotheruser", email: "second@test.com", name: "anothername", canRead: 1, canWrite: 1, canDelete: 1
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT users.userId, users.username, users.email, users.name,
CASE WHEN(
  SELECT DISTINCT permissions.permission
  FROM permissions
  WHERE permissions.permission = 'canRead' AND users.userId = permissions.userId
) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'canRead',
CASE WHEN(
  SELECT DISTINCT permissions.permission
  FROM permissions
  WHERE permissions.permission = 'canWrite' AND users.userId = permissions.userId
) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'canWrite',
CASE WHEN(
  SELECT DISTINCT permissions.permission
  FROM permissions
  WHERE permissions.permission = 'canDelete' AND users.userId = permissions.userId
) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'canDelete',
FROM users
LEFT JOIN permissions
ON permissions.userId = users.userId
GROUP BY users.userId
```

The more permissions I add the slower the query becomes. How can I write this query in a more simplified and especially performant way?

Comment: Just to be crystal clear here. Did you create those tables yourself, or are those the system tables?

Comment: You already have `permissions` joined, why do you need all those subqueries to look in that same table again? I am also not sure mySQL knows which table you mean with `permissions`, is that the table in the subquery or the joined table?

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by single JOIN and some data manipulation:

```
SELECT 
    users.userId, users.username, users.email, users.name,
    COUNT(IF(permissions.permission = 'canRead', 1, null)) > 0 'canRead',
    COUNT(IF(permissions.permission = 'canWrite', 1, null)) > 0 'canWrite',
    COUNT(IF(permissions.permission = 'canDelete', 1, null)) > 0 'canDelete'
FROM users
LEFT JOIN permissions ON users.userId = permissions.userId
GROUP BY users.userId, users.username, users.email, users.name;
```

[MySQL JOIN fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/cd0d390257fdd5e6689d8baf522f5d7f/)

Comment: why did you group out all the 4 fields when they are all from the same record userId?

Comment: Read here about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Forbs Probably because with only userId the query would break once MySql isn't running in cheat mode. I.e. with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of it, I guess all the servers I use have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it. Max 'em.

```
SELECT u.userId, u.username, u.email, u.name
, MAX(CASE WHEN p.permission = 'canRead' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS canRead
, MAX(CASE WHEN p.permission = 'canWrite' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS canWrite
, MAX(CASE WHEN p.permission = 'canDelete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS canDelete
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN permissions p
  ON p.userId = u.userId
GROUP BY u.userId, u.username, u.email, u.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove this (it seems to serve no purpose, but takes time):

  ```
    LEFT JOIN  permissions  ON permissions.userId = users.userId
  ```
- This index on permissions:  `INDEX(userId,  permission)` may help.  (See caveat below.)
- Without the `LEFT JOIN`, the `GROUP BY` becomes unnecessary; get rid of it.
- Switch to `EXISTS`.  For example

  ```
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT permissions.permission
            FROM  permissions
            WHERE  permissions.permission = 'canRead'
              AND  users.userId = permissions.userId 
    ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'canRead',
  ```

-->

```
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM permissions
            WHERE  permissions.permission = 'canRead'
              AND  users.userId = permissions.userId 
    ) AS 'canRead',
```

Exists() is likely to be faster than the other Answers because `EXISTS` is a "semi-join", meaning that it stops when it discovers a matching row.  The others have to check all the relevant rows, which takes longer.

- "users: (userId, username, email, name) permissions: (id, userId, permission)" implies that you have two unique keys on `users`?  Is `id` needed at all?  If you get rid of `id` and make `userId` the `PRIMARY KEY`, then my index recommendation above becomes redundant.
- For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.